# Package dependencies for offline installation

Tags: python, dependencies, package

How to package dependencies so when someone retrieves the repository they just have to install the dependencies offline. All that I could find was about giving a list of required dependencies to be downloaded..

Comment: Your question might be confuse others, will you please explain what exactly you want to try ?

Comment: I suspect that list of dependencies you are talking about is requirements.txt... That is input for pip to download your dependencies. Still, you will need to clarify a bit what you want to do

Comment: @Lawrence: I think it might solve my problem. I want to do the exact same thing except it's on Windows and I have some package that I understood could cause some problems (like numpy). I'll look into that and get back to you